# Running a jdbc program without setting the class path for each and every time

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

"**SET CLASSPATH=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;.**" . Can anybody tell me how i can set the classpath permanently so that i will not have to set the classpath for the next time i restart my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose the `ojdbc14.jar` as an [Installed Java Extension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html)

What you need to do is to place the `ojdbc14.jar` in a specific System folder, so it get's loaded by the JVM before the classpath.

The location varies depending on the OS:

- Solaris™ Operating System: `/usr/jdk/packages/lib/ext`
- Linux: `/usr/java/packages/lib/ext`
- Microsoft Windows: `%SystemRoot%\Sun\Java\lib\ext` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\ext`

Because you'll be using the jar as an installed extension, the runtime environment will be able to find and to load its classess and you'll not be required to add them to the classpath.

Comment: And because it's working you decided to unaccept my answer. xD

Comment: Not like that dude... I don't have enough reputation for that and i joined stack overflow today . i just Edited your answer as how i did in my system ... But thanks a lot to you for your help buddy ... :)

Comment: The solution is sound and will work.  However, think always a step ahead and please consider that this adds up a step to the deploy of your solution in a production environment.  Think always to carefully document every installation requirement in environments you are surely not to manage.  Specially when modifying the JRE installation with extensions and/or security policies that may be overlooked when sys admins upgrade the JRE version to the next one - making your JRE directory to fall irrelevant, with everything you left there

Answer (score 0):

set it under environment variable. Here are the steps. Then you don't have do it every time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html